# Order two separate tables by date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering whether it's possible to loop through two separate tables, ordering them by their date. I don't want to Join the tables together.

Example:

Table 1:

```
| id | title | date      |
| 1  | hello | 2013-07-07|
| 2  | world | 2013-07-13|
```

Table 2:

```
| id | saying | date      |
| 1  | this   | 2013-07-14|
| 2  | that   | 2013-07-10|
```

I would want to loop through these using a combination of PHP and MySQL to display as:

```
1 hello 2013-07-07
2 that  2013-07-10
2 world 2013-07-13
1 this  2013-07-14
```

While I realise this is probably not possible it would make the management my project much easier if there was a clever solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why yes. Yes, it is possible. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a union and sort the result

```
SELECT id, title, date  
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT id, saying, date  
FROM Table2
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: a `UNION ALL` operator might be more appropriate, if removing duplicates is not a requirement, or is not desirable.

Comment: Fair point, and probably a bit quicker

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I always treated UNION as something to JOIN tables together. Thank you for your quick reply.